# secondary index on column store dbs

Tags: store, hbase

Is there any column store database that supports secondary index ? 
I know HBase does, but it's not there yet.

Haggai.

Answer (score 1):

By storing overlapping projections in different sort orders, column stores based on the C-Store architecture (so, as far as commericial implementations go, Vertica) natively support secondary indexes.
See http://db.csail.mit.edu/projects/cstore/vldb.pdf

Also check out MonetDb, which treats "create index" statements as hints for its self-organizing engine.

Comment: C-Store development discontinued as FOSS, but continued as the commercial [Vertica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertica) DBMS. I've "salvaged" the final published version and have made sure it builds on modern-day (2020) systems - in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/eyalroz/c-store).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in this class [IndexSpecification](http://hadoop.apache.org/hbase/docs/r0.19.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/tableindexed/IndexSpecification.html) which is part of r0.19.3.

[Here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-883?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=12643744) you can see how to use it (maybe they have a test for that as well)
I've never used that and don't if it performs well. please share with us your results.

good luck
 -- Yonatan

Answer (score 0):

Sybase IQ supports as many indexes as you might ever desire on every column and even within a column (e.g. the word index which lets you stay with defaults or specify your own delimiter)